# How do I add to a set based on a specific predicate in Java?

Tags: java, set, guava, predicate

I have a set in Java containing people:

```
Set<Person> uniquePeople = new HashSet<Person>();
```

I also have a list of a ton of people (of whom some possess the same name, eg. there is more than one "Bob" in the world).

```
List<Person> theWorld = // ... a BIG list of people
```

I want to iterate through this list and add a person to the `uniquePeople` set if and only if their name doesn't exist in the set, eg:

```
for (Person person : theWorld) {
    uniquePeople.add(person IFF uniquePeople.doesNotContain(person.name));
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Java? Also, Guava might do this (?) but I haven't used it at all so I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: You could sort both lists and then compare each value in the lists, similar to how merge sort merges values... this would be an effective way of doing it, if you have to code something.

Comment: Perhaps you can override the toString() method of your Person class and use this to print the person's name and then have 2 sets that you can try to add stuff to (assuming you get a "true" back if your add was successful to the first set which is just of the name)... just an idea.

Comment: how about uniquePeople.addAll(theWorld);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better option would be to abandon using a Set and instead use a `Map<String, Person>` (keyed off of the name).

If you want to use a set, I suggest you use a new object type (that will just contain a name and maybe a reference to a Person).

Make sure you override equals so that it will only compare the names and then you can get a set of all unique people.

You could also subclass person to override the equals to do what you want.

Sets by definition will not do what you want with just a person since they depend entirely on using equals so these are your workaround options. You could also implement (or find online) a set that takes a comparator to use instead of relying on equals but I don't think such a class exists in standard java.

Comment: Uh, yeah, that seems ridiculously obvious now. A map will work great. Can you edit your answer to make the Map the top portion and I'll accept asap. EDIT: Thanks, just waiting out the timer.

Answer (score 3):

Use Guava's [`Equivalence`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) to wrap your objects if you don't want to (or can't) override equals and hashCode:

```
Set<Equivalence.Wrapper<Person>> set = Sets.newHashSet();
Equivalence<Person> personEquivalence = Equivalence.onResultOf(
    new Function<Person, String>() {
      @Override public String apply(Person p) {
        return p.name;
      }
    });
set.add(personEquivalence.wrap(new Person("Joe", "Doe")));
set.add(personEquivalence.wrap(new Person("Joe", "Doe")));
set.add(personEquivalence.wrap(new Person("Jane", "Doe")));
System.out.println(set);
// [PersonEquivalence@8813f2.wrap(Person{firstName=Jane, lastName=Doe}),
//  PersonEquivalence@8813f2.wrap(Person{firstName=Joe, lastName=Doe})]
```

@DanielWilliams has a good idea too, but using `Equivalence.Wrapper` is more self-documenting - after all you don't want to create new object other than wrapper.

Comment: It's nice but not as Lispy as I thought it would be - plus it's an extra library. ;)

Comment: @sdasdadas Java is not _Lispy_ at all - I even don't use Emacs while coding in Java :(. Anyway, Guava is worth using in every Java project IMO - it saves me much time in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why people got downvoted here.

You absolutely want a Set. Not only do your requirements meet the definition and functionality of 'Set' but Set implementations are designed to quickly identify duplicates either via hash or Comparative identity.

Let's say you had a List implementation that took a deligate and a predicate:

List uniquePeople = new PredicatedList(new ArrayList(),UnqiuePersonPredicate.getInstance())

```
public class PredicatedList<T> implements List<T> {

    private List<T> delegate = null;
    private Predicate<T> predicate;

    public PredicatedList<List<T> delegate, Predicate p) {
     this.delegate = delegate;
     this.predicate = p;
    }
   // implement list methods here and apply 'p' before calling your insertion functions

   public boolean add(Person p) {
     if(predicate.apply(p))
        delegate.add(p);

   }
}
```

For this to work you would need to have a predicate that iterates over the list to find an equal element. This is an O(N) operation. If you use HashSet then it's O(1) < n < O(N). Your amortized identity check is the load factor * N. And, usually much closer to O(1)

If you use TreeSet you will get O(log(n)) because the elements are sorted by identity and you need only log(n) time to binary search.

Define hashCode()/equals based on 'name' or whatever you want and use HashSet or use TreeSet and define Comparable/Comparator

If your return type MUST be a List then do:
Set uniquePeople = new HashSet();
uniquePeople.add(...);

List people = new LinkedList(uniquePeople);

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that overriding `equals` is a global solution for a local problem. Another person mentioned making a wrapper, and then overriding `equals`, which would be preferable (to me, at least) to overriding the `equals` method for one use.

Comment: An interesting though. But, look at "equivalence" below and it's way more complicated. An alternative approach I have used is to have multiple Comparators that define identity different ways. Equality is thusly defined as compareTo() == 0  Handy when having to define identity other than by hash/equals (think hibernate). 

My mantra on code is: There are good ideas, bad ideas and what you have to do to get your job done. Dogma about "one size fits all" solutions is an anathema to good software. Bottom line: Good wisdom. The poster should take all this advice in context and decide for themself

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with guava, the only thing is that Person is going to need an equals/hashcode method.

```
ImmutableSet<String> smallList = ImmutableSet.of("Eugene","Bob");
ImmutableSet<String> bigList   = ImmutableSet.of("Eugene","Bob","Alex","Bob","Alex");

System.out.println(Iterables.concat(smallList, Sets.difference(bigList, smallList)));

//output is going to be : [Eugene, Bob, Alex]
```